# Payum integration in Symfony 5 returns error "no container set"

Tags: php, symfony, payum

I've installed Payum in my Symfony 5 project (using  [these instructions](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/788/files#diff-775a456d8bd1590f53de08ad6a4a78c8) ). When I try to call the route `/payment/capture/qrak82BzjIVUnylasjXwwC5q3DKw7EPJYQ1z1IYHaHY` Symfony finds the route but doesn't even arrive to open the relative controller, because it gives me the error: 
"Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\CaptureController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber"?

I googled for that error, but it seems extremely rare and I don't understand how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at https://github.com/Payum/Payum/issues/850

zspine commented 25 days ago
As a temporary fix I have configured the service manually under `config/services.yaml` and it works ...

```
Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\CaptureController:
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

Also digging deeper from that post, theres a link to https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/issues/507

Having more of the services

## config/services.yaml

```
services:
    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\AuthorizeController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\CancelController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\CaptureController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\NotifyController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\PayoutController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\RefundController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']

    Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\SyncController:
        calls:
            - method: setContainer
              arguments: ['@service_container']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a misconfiguration issue from code owners, you can auto tag entire directory:

```
# config/services.yaml

Payum\Bundle\PayumBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../vendor/payum/payum-bundle/Controller/*'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```